# How to make our own file type

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to know can we create a our own file type with extension and our own icon like
When I click a button it's saves the data in text boxes as check.myextension .

```
        Dim writer As System.IO.StreamWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText("check.myextension ")
        Timer1.Stop()
        writer.Write(ControlChars.Quote)
        writer.Write(GlobalVariables.string)
        writer.Write(ControlChars.Quote)
        writer.Write(",")
        writer.Write(ControlChars.Quote)
        writer.Write(GlobalVariables.var)
        writer.Write(ControlChars.Quote)
```

This is working and I can load this by using this

```
    Dim reader As System.IO.StreamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText("check.myextension")
    Timer1.Stop()
    Dim contents As String = reader.ReadToEnd
    reader.Close()

    Dim items() As String = contents.Split(",")
    GlobalVariables.string = items(0).Replace(ControlChars.Quote, String.Empty)
    GlobalVariables.var= items(1).Replace(ControlChars.Quote, String.Empty)
```

these all are working but I want add a icon and file type description to it how do I do this? Please tell me if anyone know... In **Visual Basic .net forms** I don't know c# , c++ .
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpSkP.png)

Comment: It is a job for an installer, not your app.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-register-a-file-type-for-a-new-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register the new filetype in the registry

This should get you started:

```
Dim rk As RegistryKey
Dim path As String
path = Application.StartupPath & "\myextension.ico"
rk = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(".myentension\DefaultIcon")
rk.SetValue("DefaultIcon", path)
```

Comment: Where do I add this content ?

Comment: Probably as part of the startup of your app, but it's really up to you. However as Hans Passant mentioned, the best way to do it is as part of an installer if you have one.